# How to suppress out of grep in ksh

Tags: ksh

I have the below programme

```
query=$selectPart"${indxFile}"$filePart

if find /home/test -name "${cobolFile}"| xargs grep $query;then
   print "${cobolFile}"
    while read -r scriptFile;do
        print " "

    done < listScripts.txt
```

But the output of the grep query is being printed to stdout. How do I suppress this output?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work

```
if find /home/test -name "${cobolFile}"| xargs grep $query | grep -v grep;then
```

Comment: What does grep -v grep mean?

Comment: `grep -v str` will exclude `str` from the matches, in this case, grep will exclude itself

Comment: I tried `if find standardization/runtest -name "${script
File}" | xargs grep $scriptQuery | grep -v grep;` . I can still see the output of grep

Comment: Sorry I have no idea why it is not working, can you try to enclose ` xargs grep $scriptQuery` with parenthesis? (or whatever ksh supports for statement grouping)

Answer (score 0):

`if find /home/test -name "${cobolFile}"| xargs grep -q $query;then`

This shd do the trick :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$(find /home/test -name "${cobolFile}" -exec grep $query {} + )" ]
then
  print "${cobolFile}"
  while read -r scriptFile
  do
    print " "
  done < listScripts.txt
fi
```